# Adding a column to the task board

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I've been given the admin task for our company Jira implementation.  There has been zero handover from the previous guy which aint helpful.

The previous guy had, in the Task Board, four columns;

1. To Do
2. In Progress
3. To Verify
4. Done

Now I need to add another column between "To Do" and "In Progress" but am at a loss as to how to do that.

I've been told to be careful when doing this as it may screw up the workflow.  This is the reason I'm coming here for this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: configure your workflow.
Based on your JIRA version you can either edit an active or passive workflow. If you are new to JRIA my best bet would be to create a test project edit the workflow to your satisfaction. Atlassian has very good documentation about [customizing workflows](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Workflow).

Step 2: I believe you are using greenhopper which has a taskboard. Any changes to the task board configuration does no affect the workflow. play around with these using the documentation given [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Configuring+your+Task+Board+Settings). Just be careful with the right most column ***done*** and assign the closed statuses with it, else this might screw up the reports.